# Syntax error when using date format options

Tags: bash

Running on MacOS.
Learning bash so bear with me. I have a simple bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

RUN_DATE=`date +%Y_%m_%d`
python3 /path/to/some/builder.py --date=$RUN_DATE
```

Where I have a program called builder.py and it takes an *date* input. I want to write a bash script that sets $RUN_DATE to whatever the date it is at the time of the run. It will be read in Python as a string input. However, I get the following error:

```
RUN_DATE=`date +%Y_%m_%d`
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there something obvious I'm overlooking to get this to work?

Comment: Sure you're running that with bash and not some other program?

Comment: Are you trying to run the bash script with python? If so, you might want to try running it with bash like this: ```./YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.sh```

Comment: As an aside, you want `$(date +%Y_%m_%d)` instead of the obsolescent backtick syntax from the 1990s. Try http://shellcheck.net/  for checks against many common beginner errors.

Comment: As a further aside, Python itself is quite capable of checking the date; `from datetime import datetime` and then `date = datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y_%m_%d")`